# In proving trigonometric identities, is it acceptable to start with the simpler side and manipulate it to the form of the complicated side?

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, solution-verification

In proving trigonometric identities in the form of LHS = RHS, we usually manipulate the more complicated side to obtain the result from the other side. What if I start from the simpler side and manipulate it to the form in the complicated side? Is the proof acceptable?

eg.

$$\sin(x)=\dfrac{1-\cos(2x)}{2\sin(x)}$$

I prove the identity from LHS.

Comment: Almost surely "yes". You can [edit] the question to show us an example to be sure. In this case the left side is defined for $x=0$ but the right side is not, so there's some subtlety. Ue mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: In general, if you have any demonstration that looks like RHS = expression-1 = expression-2 = ... = expression-n = LHS, then your demonstration also represents LHS = ... = RHS.  Simply reverse the steps.  As the comment of @EthanBolker suggests, you have to watch out for such things as [1] you can't divide by $0$ or [2] $x=2 \implies x^2 = 4$, but $x^2 = 4$ does not imply $x=2$.

Comment: Thank you @EthanBolker    . I would like to know that there is no such concept as ' mathematical proof is from complicated form to simplest form, not the other way round ' right?

Comment: Thank you @user2661923.

Comment: You are correct. There is nothing in the idea of a proof that says it has to go from one particular expression to the other. As @user2661923 says, you do have to be careful to check that the implication in each individual step really goes both ways.

Comment: Yes. $\frac {x²}{x}$ is not necessarily equal to $x$, as that would imply $\frac {0}{0}=0$, for $x=0$, which is not the case. What I mean to say is that you will have to follow exactly the same steps in reverse order(relative to starting from the opposite side).